# How to reduce the computation time of this series expansion?

Tags: performance-tuning, series-expansion, timing

I have a complicated function `gg[Delta,l][z1,z2]` which is given in the sample code below. I would like to expand this function for as many `l`'s (even) as possible and to an order `zmax` which should be as high as possible (`l=50`, `zmax=100` would be amazing) for $z_1, z_2 
\sim 1$. Unfortunately the computation time is huge: for `zmax=20`, `l=0` (see code below) takes $30$ seconds on my computer; `l=2` takes 120 seconds; ... This is taking way too much time, is there a way to make this code run faster?

The script so far:

```
zmax = 20;
l = 0;
gg[\[CapitalDelta]_, l][z1_, z2_] = Series[Sum[Factor[(Pochhammer[\[CapitalDelta]/2 - 1/2,n] Pochhammer[\[CapitalDelta]/2 - 1/2,n] Pochhammer[(\[CapitalDelta] + l)/2, n])/(Pochhammer[\[CapitalDelta] - 2 + 1,n] Pochhammer[(\[CapitalDelta] + l)/2 + 1/2, n]) (Pochhammer[-(l/2), m] Pochhammer[1/2 - l/2 - 1/2,m] Pochhammer[1 - l/2 - \[CapitalDelta]/2, m])/(Pochhammer[2 - 2 - l, m] Pochhammer[3/2 - l/2 - \[CapitalDelta]/2, m])Pochhammer[(\[CapitalDelta] + l)/2, n - m]/Pochhammer[(\[CapitalDelta] + l)/2 - 1/2,n - m] HypergeometricPFQ[{-n, -m, 1/2, (\[CapitalDelta] - l)/2 - 2 + 1}, {-((\[CapitalDelta] + l)/2) + 1 - n, (\[CapitalDelta] + l)/2 - m, (\[CapitalDelta] - l)/2 - 2 + 3/2}, 1] 4^(m - n)/(n! m!) ((1 - z1) (1 - z2))^((\[CapitalDelta] - l)/2 + m + n) (1 - z1 z2)^(l - 2 m)Hypergeometric2F1[(\[CapitalDelta] + l)/2 - m + n, (\[CapitalDelta] + l)/2 - m + n, \[CapitalDelta] + l - 2 m + 2 n, 1 - z1 z2]], {m, 0, l/2}, {n, 0, zmax}], {z1, 1,zmax}, {z2, 1, zmax}] // Normal;
Clear[l]
```

Comment: Okay I found elsewhere one trick that already strongly reduces the time of computation: set `z1->1-t y1`, expand for $t \sim 0$, set `t=1` and replace again `y1->1-z1`. With that I reach `l=10` for `zmax=20` in 120 seconds. I am still interested in other suggestions.

Comment: What is the value of `\[CapitalDelta]`? `z1,z2` appear as arguments and although as `summation varaibles` !!!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann No `z1` and `z2` are variables for the series expansion. They are still present in the final expression. `\[CapitalDelta]` should remain symbolic, as I also need to take some derivatives with respect to that variable later on.

Comment: If yes, it's probably wrong to pass `z1,z2` as argument !

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Ah why? It seems to work fine. On the rhs I have (schematically) a function of the form `1+z1+z2+z1 z2+...`.

Comment: ...and on the left handside you pass `z1,z2` as argument? You don't need these arguments in your function definition I think.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Does that slow the computation you think? I always use the same variable names throughout my script, so I guess it makes no difference whether they are passed as variables or not.